# Having trouble setting up spree commerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, spree

I am using docker to setup on my mac m1 machine for spree commerce. When I run the bin/setup script I am hitting the following error and I am unable to move forward. I am not sure what is the issue.

I followed the exact same step as advised by the official website at https://dev-docs.spreecommerce.org/getting-started/installation.

Below is the last lines of the output at terminal which exits when setting up node:

```
#5 18.75 ## Running `apt-get update` for you...
#5 18.75 
#5 18.75 + apt-get update
#5 18.80 Hit:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
#5 18.80 Hit:2 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
#5 18.80 Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
#5 18.83 Get:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x buster InRelease [4584 B]
#5 19.02 Get:5 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x buster/main arm64 Packages [766 B]
#5 19.03 Fetched 5350 B in 0s (20.6 kB/s)
#5 19.03 Reading package lists...
#5 19.35 
#5 19.35 ## Run `sudo apt-get install -y nodejs` to install Node.js 12.x and npm
#5 19.35 ## You may also need development tools to build native addons:
#5 19.35      sudo apt-get install gcc g++ make
#5 19.35 ## To install the Yarn package manager, run:
#5 19.35      curl -sL https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | sudo tee /usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg >/dev/null
#5 19.35      echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/yarnkey.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
#5 19.35      sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install yarn
#5 19.35 
#5 19.35 
#5 19.36 Reading package lists...
#5 19.68 Building dependency tree...
#5 19.74 Reading state information...
#5 19.81 The following NEW packages will be installed:
#5 19.81   nodejs
#5 19.89 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
#5 19.89 Need to get 17.4 MB of archives.
#5 19.89 After this operation, 92.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
#5 19.89 Get:1 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x buster/main arm64 nodejs arm64 12.22.5-1nodesource1 [17.4 MB]
#5 21.43 debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
#5 21.45 Fetched 17.4 MB in 2s (11.4 MB/s)
#5 21.47 Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
(Reading database ... 26279 files and directories currently installed.)
#5 21.48 Preparing to unpack .../nodejs_12.22.5-1nodesource1_arm64.deb ...
#5 21.48 Unpacking nodejs (12.22.5-1nodesource1) ...
#5 22.68 Setting up nodejs (12.22.5-1nodesource1) ...
#5 22.73 Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
#5 22.89 gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
#5 22.89 Segmentation fault
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update -yq   && apt-get upgrade -yq   && apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends build-essential curl git-core vim passwd unzip cron gcc wget netcat   && apt-get update   && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends imagemagick postgresql-client   && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_12.x | bash -   && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nodejs   && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -   && echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list   && apt-get update && apt-get install yarn   && apt-get update   && apt-get install -y xvfb   && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -   && echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list   && apt-get update   && apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable   && mkdir $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR   && wget -q --continue -P $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip"   && unzip $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR/chromedriver* -d $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR]: exit code: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try reaching out on [Spree Slack](https://spree-commerce.slack.com/join/shared_invite/zt-ico7d35e-OeoAYXKO8XNtrZR1ZvBb5A#/shared-invite/email) for support.

Answer (score 0):

This is now fixed, just use `git pull` or re-download the starter